# Comparing arrays to determine win conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, scope

I'm trying to create a simple tic-tac-toe game but I've run into a problem. I created a 2D array called winConditions to be compared with xMoves and oMoves to determine when someone has won, but nothing seems to be happening when I call my determineWin function. I'm really bad with arrays and scope so I'm assuming the problem lies with an incorrect scope issue but this is a bit over my head. Could somebody help determine the problem with this code?
http://jsfiddle.net/Skww6/1/
(This is the function that I probably have my mistake in)

```
var determineWin = function (pMoves) {
    var winAlert;
    for (var i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) {
        if (winConditions[i].length > pMoves.length) {
            continue;
        }
    for (var j = 0; j < winConditions[i].length; j++) {
        winAlert = false;
        for (var k = 0; k < pMoves.length; k++) {
            if (pMoves[k] === winConditions[i][j]) {
                winAlert = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (!winAlert) break;
    }
        if (winAlert) {
            alert(currentPlayer + "wins!");
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to quote the items in your array.

In your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Skww6/1/),

Change:

```
var winConditions = [[c1, c2, c3], [c4, c5, c6], [c7, c8, c9], [c1,c4, c7], [c2, c5, c8], [c3, c6, c9], [c1, c5, c9], [c3, c5, c7]];
```

To:

```
var winConditions = [['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], ['c4', 'c5', 'c6'], ['c7', 'c8', 'c9'], ['c1','c4', 'c7'], ['c2', 'c5', 'c8'], ['c3', 'c6', 'c9'], ['c1', 'c5', 'c9'], ['c3', 'c5', 'c7']];
```

And your code above should work just fine.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Skww6/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus - Feel free. I stole it from someone else! :)